# Callback functions with different arguments

Tags: c++, c

I have two functions with a little different functionality, so I can't make them as template functions.

```
int func64(__int64 a) {
  return (int) a/2; 
} 
int func32(int a) {
    return a--; 
}
```

Depending on variable b64, I would like to call func64 or func32. I don't want check if b64 is true many times in my code, so I use pointers to functions.

```
void do_func(bool b64) {
    typedef int (*pfunc32)(int);
    typedef int (*pfunc64)(__int64);
    pfunc32 call_func; 
    if (b64) 
        call_func = func64; //error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(__int64)' to 'pfunc32'
    else
        call_func = func32;
    //...
    call_func(6); 
}
```

How can I avoid this error and cast call_func to pfunc32 or pfunc64?

Comment: The two function types are incompatible - require different types of arguments. What are you trying to achieve by attempting to cast them both to the same type - you wouldn't know what argument to pass.

Comment: The short answer is `std::function`. The long answer is there's probably a different problem that needs to be fixed first.

Comment: @Mat I need to call func32() or func64() depending on flag b64

Comment: Then do just that. You don't need `call_func` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language requires all functions called through the same function pointer to have the same prototype.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could use the pointer/cast aproach already mentioned (which satisfies this requirement at the loss of type safety) or pass a union instead:

```
union u32_64
{
    __int64 i64;
    int i32;
};

int func64(union u32_64 a) {
   return (int) a.i64/2;
} 

int func32(union u32_64 a) {
    return --a.i32;
}     

void do_func(bool b64) {
    typedef int (*pfunc)(union u32_64);

    pfunc call_func;   
    if (b64)            
        call_func = func64;
    else                    
        call_func = func32;         
    //...                               

    union u32_64 u = { .i64 = 6 };
    call_func(u);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Pass a void pointer and cast it in the function body.

Of course this means less compiler control if you use the wrong type; if you call `func64` and pass an `int` to it the program will compile and produce wrong results without giving you any tip of what is going wrong.

```
int func64(void *a) {
   __int64 b = *((__int64*) a);  
   return (int) b/2; 
} 

int func32(void *a) {
   int b = *((int *) a)
   return b-1; 
}
```

Comment: Tnank you for the answer. Probably you hasn't gotten what I meant. I need to call func32() or func64() depending on flag b64

Comment: What you want to do is possible with this solution because now the two functions have the same return type and argument types

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, please note that function `func32` is returning the input argument **as is**.

This is because with `return a--`, you are returning the value of `a` **before** decrementing it.

Perhaps you meant to `return a-1` instead?

In any case, you can simply declare this function as `int func32(__int64 a)`.

This way, it will have the same prototype as function `func64`, but will work exactly as before.

BTW, calling a function through a pointer might be more "expensive" than a simple branch operation, so depending on your application, you might be better off with a simple `if`/`else` conditional statement...

Answer (score 0):

> I need to call func32() or func64() depending on flag b64

So do that:

```
void do_func(bool b64) {
    if (b64) 
        func64(6);
    else
        func32(6);
}
```

Comment: Nice! I have a lot places where I need call this. I don't like this solution(

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper for `func64`:

```
int func64_as_32(int a) {
    return func64(a);
}
```

Now you can assign either `func32` or `func64_as_32` to `call_func` since they have the same signature. The value you pass in, `6`, has type `int` so passing it to `func64_as_32` has the same effect as passing it directly to `func64`.

If you have call sites where you pass in a value of type `__int64` then you'd do it the other way around, wrap `func32`.

Comment: What if it will not be 6? for example it can be 4294967354

Comment: @lo.ol: Then take the option of wrapping `func32`. No matter how you do it, trying to call `func32` with a value that's too big for `int` is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

As `bool` in `C++` converts to `int` ( `true` => `1`, `false` => `0` ) you can use `b64` as array index. So take SJuan76's advice, convert your functions prototype to `int f(void*)` and put them into array `int (*array_fun[2])(void* x);` . You can call these functions then like that :

```
int p = 6; 
array_fun[b64](&p);
```